# Android fragments and adapter

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I have the following code which is a fragment that has a recycler view and I have an adapter, debugging my code shows that the adapter is getting called after the fragment returns the result, although I am creating an instance of the adapter and setting it to the recycler view and setting the wanted results before returning the fragment. can someone help explaining what's happening I am new to Android with a bit of java experience.

Here is my fragment class:

```
package com.clowiz.ui.gallery;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProviders;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.clowiz.MainActivity;
import com.clowiz.R;
import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;

import java.util.List;

import static android.app.Activity.RESULT_OK;

public class GalleryFragment extends Fragment {

    public static final int ADD_UNIVERSITY_CODE = 1;
    private GalleryViewModel galleryViewModel;
    private UniversityViewModel universityViewModel;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_gallery, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        FloatingActionButton buttonAddUniversity = view.findViewById(R.id.button_add_university);
        buttonAddUniversity.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), AddUniversityActivity.class);
                startActivityForResult(intent, ADD_UNIVERSITY_CODE);
            }
        });

        RecyclerView recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(view.getContext()));

        final UniversityAdapter adapter = new UniversityAdapter();
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        universityViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(UniversityViewModel.class);
        universityViewModel.getAllUniversities().observe(this, new Observer<List<University>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable List<University> unis) {
                adapter.setUniversities(unis);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(requestCode == ADD_UNIVERSITY_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            String name = data.getStringExtra(AddUniversityActivity.EXTRA_NAME);
            University uni = new University(name);
            universityViewModel.insert(uni);
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "uni added successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "uni not saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }
}
```

Here is my adapter:

```
package com.clowiz.ui.gallery;

import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.clowiz.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class UniversityAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<UniversityAdapter.UniversityHolder> {

    private List<University> universities = new ArrayList<>();

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public UniversityHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.university_item, parent, false);
        return new UniversityHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull UniversityHolder holder, int position) {
        University university = universities.get(position);
        holder.textViewId.setText(String.valueOf(university.getId()));
        holder.textViewName.setText(university.getName());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return universities.size();
    }

    public void setUniversities(List<University> universities) {
        this.universities = universities;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    class UniversityHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private TextView textViewId;
        private TextView textViewName;

        public UniversityHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            textViewId = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_id);
            textViewName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_name);
        }
    }

}
```

Here is my viewModel:

```
package com.clowiz.ui.gallery;

import android.app.Application;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.lifecycle.AndroidViewModel;
import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData;

import java.util.List;

public class UniversityViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {

    private UniversityRepository repository;
    private LiveData<List<University>> allUniversities;

    public UniversityViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
        super(application);
        repository = new UniversityRepository(application);
        allUniversities = repository.getAllUniversities();
    }

    public void insert(University university) {
        repository.insert(university);
    }

    public void update(University university) {
        repository.update(university);
    }

    public void delete(University university) {
        repository.delete(university);
    }

    public LiveData<List<University>> getAllUniversities() {
        return allUniversities;
    }
}
```

Here is my listItem:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.023">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_view_id"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:text="Id"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"></TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_view_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@id/text_view_id"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/text_view_id"
            android:text="Name"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"></TextView>
    </RelativeLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Here is my fragment view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="159dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="182dp"
        tools:listitem="@layout/university_item">
    </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/button_add_university"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add_black_24dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.21"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.916"  />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here is my repository:

package com.clowiz.ui.gallery;

```
public class UniversityViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {

    private UniversityRepository repository;
    private LiveData<List<University>> allUniversities;

    public UniversityViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
        super(application);
        repository = new UniversityRepository(application);
        allUniversities = repository.getAllUniversities();
    }

    public void insert(University university) {
        repository.insert(university);
    }

    public void update(University university) {
        repository.update(university);
    }

    public void delete(University university) {
        repository.delete(university);
    }

    public LiveData<List<University>> getAllUniversities() {
        return allUniversities;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using the same layout `R.layout.fragment_gallery` for both your UniversityViewHolder and GalleryFragment

Comment: @Networks I have edited the code and it's working, but im not sure if it the correct way to do the add and list operations with fragments

Comment: No need to worry everything looks good.

Comment: To improve recycler update consider using a DiffUtil together with your RecyclerAdapter. Since you are loading from room you could also use the Paging Library from Architecture Components together with Room to load your Recycler items. The PagingAdapter enforces you to define a DiffUtil

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have the correct design around this, you should move all that code to `onViewCreated` instead and keep `onCreateView` as simple as:

```
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_gallery, container, false);
}
```

**Edit:** Also, provide a `LayoutManager` to the `RecyclerView` as I've missed that on my initial read.

And then you can use the `view` instance of `onViewCreated` to get your other views.

Comment: still the same result

Comment: What do you mean when you say *Fragment returns the result*, what result? Do you mean the result of the data-set or the `onActivityResult`? Can you add some logging and paste some logs so it's clearer to understand?

Comment: I mean the view, which is returned from this line: inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_gallery, container, false);

Comment: I have edited the code as you suggested, and I have added a line to my code which is: recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(view.getContext())); now the page is showing the records but its like pages in the same view. so when I scroll down in the page I will find the next record with the same components from the page duplicated again

Comment: Can you also provide a snipped from your `ViewModel` where you forward the data through your `LiveData`? But to ensure a good dataset, you can look into using `DiffUtil.Callback()`

Comment: I have edited the code and it's working, but im not sure if it the correct way to do the add and list operations with fragments

Comment: Can you show what happens on `getAllUniversities` from the `Repository`. I suspect you create new objects so without a Diff it sees them as different and adds it again. If you can share that as well I can give you a clear example of how it can be improved.

Comment: I have added the repository

Answer (score 0):

your problem is that once you open a fragment, a list of uni's is displayed by default. when you click on add a new uni using the floating button, you go to 'AddUniversityActivity' and expect when you get back to see the new one added with no duplicates or weird behaviour.

here is what I think you should do :

1) override|impelment hashcode on the class `University` to make each instance unique ( maybe use university id ).

2) use [HashSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) as a collection for your universities instead of List.

since you are learning, take a look at [observable design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) , [activity lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle) , [fragmnet lifecycle](https://www.journaldev.com/9266/android-fragment-lifecycle) .

Comment: I have edited the code and it's working, but im not sure if it the correct way to do the add and list operations with fragments, I will do what you have suggested as well but is it necessary?

Comment: I think there is no need for this.